problem installing pip install scikit-image==0.21.0
I'm getting an error when trying to install scikit-image on win11 x64. I have installed VS build tools and I'm running Python 3.10.0 (needs to be this version).
C:\Rope>pip install scikit-image==0.21.0

Collecting scikit-image==0.21.0
Using cached scikit_image-0.21.0.tar.gz (22.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies … done
Getting requirements to build wheel … done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) … error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]

meson setup C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c.mesonpy-h9pbs5zs -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c.mesonpy-h9pbs5zs\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.5.1
Source dir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c
Build dir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c.mesonpy-h9pbs5zs
Build type: native build
Project name: scikit-image
Project version: 0.21.0
C compiler for the host machine: ccache gcc (gcc 13.1.0 “gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-msvcrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0”)
C linker for the host machine: gcc ld.bfd 2.40
C++ compiler for the host machine: ccache c++ (gcc 13.1.0 “c++ (MinGW-W64 x86_64-msvcrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0”)
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.40
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
Library m found: YES
Checking if “-Wl,–version-script” : links: YES
Program cython found: YES (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yuvmydw0\overlay\Scripts\cython.EXE)
Program pythran found: YES (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yuvmydw0\overlay\Scripts\pythran.EXE)
Program skimage/_build_utils/copyfiles.py found: YES (python C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c\skimage/_build_utils/copyfiles.py)
Program python found: YES (C:\Rope\venv\Scripts\python.exe)
Need python for x86_64, but found x86
Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried sysconfig)
..\meson.build:69:14: ERROR: Python dependency not found
A full log can be found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uw228l9s\scikit-image_3e2bf59c71ae4599ab6dad1b6d5e9e6c.mesonpy-h9pbs5zs\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed


× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

You have the x86 version of Python installed but you need the x86_64 version as it says: Need Python for x86_64, but found x86. It should work after you install the x86_64 version.
